# how to change toolbar font-size dropdown to input field to user add manual font-size in react js

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zHLn.png)

how to change toolbar font-size dropdown to input field to user add manual font-size in react js
how to fix this problem
in react js
add custom input field
in import FroalaEditorComponent from "react-froala-wysiwyg";

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.